# Is it possible to create a non deletable and modifiable log file in Node JS

Tags: node.js, file, logging

I'm trying to create a log file. My requirement is the log file should have only append operation, the file should not be deletable or modifiable.

Is it possible with Node JS code or is it related to the hosting environment I choose?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely depends on the hosting environment you choose. Most operating support some file locking support. I'd refer you to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616281/how-can-i-lock-a-file-while-writing-to-it-asynchronously) for file locking