# Is renaming a safe way of locking files?

Tags: node.js, linux, file, locking, fs

I'm in the process of rewriting a *PHP* app for *node.js*.

One of the components involves parsing a live webserver log, using the information then writing some of it back to the log.

I lock the file to avoid overwrites (with up to 100+ entries/second  in production and parsing every hour or so, they do happen quite often without the lock) like this:

```
$fh = fopen('./my.log', 'r');
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
// parse the content, remove old entries, rewrite back the newer ones
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fh);
```

With node's *fs*, I get that there's [no native way to lock the files](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/122). Surely [there are libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616281/how-can-i-lock-a-file-while-writing-to-it-asynchronously), but my first drive was to try something like this:

```
fs.renameSync('./my.log','./my.log_') // rename the file to something else
fs.writeFileSync('./my.log_', info_to_keep, {flag: 'w+'}) // safely(!?) replace the content
fs.renameSync('./my.log_','./my.log') // rename back
// (would be done async in production, this is for quick testing only)
```

It seems to get the job done. Even if the original my.log is recreated in those few miliseconds, it'd be nicely replaced (I don't quite care about the bits of lost data! - it's all transient and used for sampling purposes).

I didn't get to test this live though, so I'm not sure if it'd work reliably. Is there any risk involved, like collisions even during the renaming process, or anything like this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Capture a snapshot of the current log file to another file for analysis?  Your demo nodejs code doesn't show where `info_to_keep` comes from so that leaves me confused.

Comment: info_to_keep holds the more recent entries, that may still be of use in a subsequent parse. everything before is no longer needed, so gets thrown away for performance and disk usage. basically, it gets the log trimmed from the start.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates `info_to_keep`?  If you're reading that from the log file, then that needs to be part of this whole process too, right?

Comment: ...end purpose being to sample a revolving dataset, as in run every hour on the last 3 hours worth of log entries.

Comment: Yes, I keep it inside the process. The part that does it is `hits.forEach(function (line) {let item = JSON.parse(line)if (item.date > last - time) { info_to_keep += line + '\n'}}`, effectively keeping only the recent log entries, verbatim.

Comment: So are you reading from the renamed file when you build `info_to_keep`?  I'm trying to figure out why you even bother renaming.  It's an append-only log file, so can't you just read the live file and ignore any partial stuff that might be at the end?  Any logging system should be appending only and not blocking other readers.  I don't even see why you need a lock or rename for this type of situation.

Comment: at that point it's just reading the log - `let hits = (fs.readFileSync(log).toString().split('\n'))` - as it's too early to actually write to the file (nothing to do yet).

Comment: This is to prevent the log from growning endlessly (1-2 GB in a year) when I only need the last couple hours' worth of data (1-2Mb) at any point.

Comment: Can you please show ALL the nodejs code for this operation.  I'm not following what the requirements are here and need to see all the relevant code.

Comment: Also, is this code in the same nodejs process that is generating the logs?  Or is it an external process from the server generating the logs.

Comment: It's a custom format `access_log` generated by the webserver (nginx). Node just uses the information there and, as a courtesy, trims old entries from the start to keep the dataset small and relevant for subsequent use. That's when it needs to put nginx on hold from writing to do its own update.

Comment: Ohh, they're nginx log files.  Well if you search for "nginx log file cutting" or "nginx log file rotating", there are lots of solutions as it's a very common need and not built into nginx (for some unknown reason).

Comment: For example, the [doc here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps) under "Log Rotation" explains how you can rename the log file, then send a signal to nginx for it to reset its logging so it stop writing to the previous file and recreates a new log file.  At that point, you have the renamed log file for your own use and nginx is happily logging to a new file.

Comment: I'm aware of that and don't want to do it, as it would interfere with my need for a consistent revolving dataset. So it has to always be up to node to decide what to keep and what to throw away (and when!)

Comment: That's just how you get a stable snapshot of the latest logs to go look at without interfering with nginx.  Your nodejs code can go grab whatever it wants.  I guess I still have no idea what you're actually trying to do.  I've tried to help - apparently unsuccessfully.  I think I'll move on now.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. 
Thing is, with rotating logs they always start blank and that's useless for my case (while reading from more than one would be a needless complication) – that's why I have the runtime trim the log on its own terms. So I just need to make sure that nginx doesn't overwrite, while node just does its thing once in a while.

Comment: Here's the full code should it be of any help: https://pastebin.com/E2QdPfhu

Comment: Well, according to one of the previous links I've given you, nginx keeps the log file open so when you rename it, nginx just keeps writing to the same file descriptor it had which is now the renamed file.  Until you signal it, it won't make a new file.  So renaming the log file won't do anything to nginx.  According to that, it will just keep writing to the renamed file.  So, I guess the answer to "Is renaming a safe way of locking files?" for nginx is "No".  It doesn't lock anything.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that because I did the testing manually. You may want to put this in as an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: I wonder now... would deleting the file (temporarily) work?

Comment: (only after also restarting nginx, apparently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to some [nginx doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps) (see the "Log Rotation" section), nginx keeps the log file open so when you rename it, nginx just keeps writing to the same file descriptor it had which is now the renamed file. Until you signal it, it won't make a new file. So renaming the log file won't do anything to nginx. According to that, it will just keep writing to the renamed file.

So, I guess the answer to ***"Is renaming a safe way of locking files?"*** for nginx is ***"No"***. It doesn't lock anything.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words: Linux process doesn't care about file name after the file has been opened by the process. The file handler would retain an address to the file on the disk and use it for IO ops.
Now, if something happens with the name while file being opened it doesn't impact the processes that already opened the handler.
What's more, even physical space is not de-allocated until all the processes close the handles to file. Meaning you can even delete the file using `rm` but as long as program reads/writes to the file, the data stays healthy.
That is the basis of NGinx log rotation mechanism btw.

Here's a good article about basics of Linux filesystem operation and Stale File Handles:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/stale-file-handles